# Yii2 validate according to related model attribute

Tags: validation, yii2

I have a form with two fields. The first field is a dropdown of a related model: partner. In validation I would like to check the other input based on this related model.

Example:

- Field 1: dropdown - partner (partner_id)
- Field 2: amount

So step 1: I have to choose partner. In model Partner there is an attribute and a value for amount_min (e.g. 10) and amount_max (e.g. 20).

Step 2: I have to type amount. (e.g. 21)

In validation I want to check if the amount in field 2 typed by the user is between amount_min and amount_max of the chosen partner.

```
public function rules() {
    return [
        ['amount', 'compare', 'compareValue' => function($model) {return $model->partner->amount_min;}, 'operator' => '>=', 'type' => 'number'],
```

But I'm getting:

> Trying to get property of non-object

How and where can I do this the best way?

Why the other question is different: at the moment when validation occurs, is related_id not yet saved, so there is no relation yet.

Comment: you are trying to validate it on the frontend and backend both? also you might need to add the `model` that is used for the `ActiveForm` and the view form

Comment: According to the error it cannot find the relation for the give partner verify if the current model has the related record in the partner, which model do you have these rules specified in ?

Comment: That's the problem that `partner_id` is not yet saved when validation occurs and so there is no related model yet to compare to.

Comment: this is confusing can you add the code? it would make more sense to understand what you are actually trying to do and what should be done, as i suspect that for your scenario you can use the when and when client too or a custom validation. `Compare` shouldnt be used here neither it could help

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Yii2 rules compareAttribute compare with attribute of another model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35113645/yii2-rules-compareattribute-compare-with-attribute-of-another-model)

Comment: also look at this answers https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12854779/validate-property-of-related-model-in-yii

Answer (score 0):

To compare and validate the "amount" field. For example:

```
protected $_partner;
//...

public function rules()
{
  return [
      ['amount', 'required'],
      ['amount',
          function ($attribute) {
              if ($this->_partner === null || $this->partner_id < $this->_partner->amount_min) {
                  $this->addError($attribute, Yii::t('user', 'The amount is less...'));
              }
          }
      ]
}
#code ...

public function beforeValidate()
{
    if (parent::beforeValidate()) {
        $this->_partner = partner::findOne($this->partner_id);
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

You can also use the model:

```
public function verify ()
     {
         if ($ this->validate() && $this->_partner) {
             #code ....
         }

         return false;
     }
```

And in the controller, call the verify method

Comment: I get the picture, but wouldn't it be possible / easier to save `partner_id` with `onChange` evtl. and then try to validate input ?

Comment: You can give a brief explanation to continue. 
Will you use it in a different model if you approve AMOUNT?

Comment: How do you mean? Sorry I don't fully understand you.